# Problems authenticating with MSAL and Azure B2C in a Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm having some difficulty getting one of the sample Xamarin.Forms/Azure applications to work with my own Azure B2C tenant, specifically [active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native).

I was able to get the sample to work out of the box, my only change being to update all the XF NuGet packages.  At this point both the Android (on my Google Pixel) and UWP versions worked perfectly; on iOS I was able to log in/out and edit the profile (it still has the known issue that iPhoneSimulator doesn't properly save tokens in the keychain, so the API and caching doesn't work, but i'm ignoring that for now until i can get an actual iPhone).  The problems started when I tried to set up and use my own B2C tenant, according to the instructions in the readme file.  Since the original sample works, it's safe to assume that the code is ok; the only changes I made were to the magic strings at the top of App.cs, and the redirect URI's stored in AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist.  So the working theory is that I either entered one of those strings wrong, or the B2C setup is wrong.  I've gone over this multiple times now and I can't find the issue.  I'm willing to bet these are all caused by the same mistake on my part, though.

**Problem 1 (solved).**  UWP app does not allow login.  Instead when the embedded browser opens I get the message "We can't connect to the service you need right now. Check your network connection or try this again later", followed by an "MsalException: WAB authentication failed" dialog once I dismiss the browser.

This was the only issue I was able to fix so far, either by commenting out this line in the UWP.MainPage constructor:

```
UserDetailsClient.Core.App.PCA.RedirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();
```

or by adding the value returned by that GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri() call (which is something like "ms-app://s-1-15-2-900855338....") to the Custom Redirect URI list of the UI app in B2C.  I would prefer simply removing the line of code, but that begs the question as to why that line of code was needed in the first place. Perhaps someone can suggest why using the ms-app:// redirect on the backend might be preferable to the msalXXXX://auth used by the other platforms.  I have no idea why the original sample worked with the ms-app:// redirect; perhaps that string is actually constant across all apps and is already defined in the sample's B2C tenant.

**Problem 2.**  Having gotten past the UWP login issue now everything works on that platform EXCEPT for the API call.  I get a 401 Unauthorized.

The API code is taken straight from the tutorial [Develop Cloud Connected Mobile Apps with Xamarin and Microsoft Azure](https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/); it's just the backend from Chapter 1, with the [Authorize] attribute added to the TodoItemController.  (All of the Chapter 1 code works, btw)  App Service Authentication is still turned off on the API itself (not the B2C tenant) in Azure. If I remove the Authorize attribute from the TodoItemController, it works, provided I also pass in the additional header ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0. Adding the header does not help with the 401, though.

Since I'm able to login, I'm guessing I have a valid access token, it's just not what the backend is expecting.  Again, this works on the sample, so I don't know how my app differs.  I suspect this issue also affects iOS and Android, but I'm not sure because unable to complete the login on those platforms.  Which brings me to...

**Problem 3.**  On Android & iOS, on clicking SIGN IN the app opens the system browser and I'm able to login in, but the subsequent redirect doesn't happen and the app remains in it's initial state.  When debugging, the line after the call to App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync() is never reached.  No exception is raised.

From what I understand this is generally due to either the redirect URI being improperly formed or forgetting to add the platform-specific redirect code (intent-filter on Android, or OpenUrl on iOS).  I've double-checked the URI a half-dozen times, and the code has to be correct since the sample worked.  I did notice the ActivityManager START entry in the Android logcat, so the browser is sending the redirect, but the app isn't responding to it for whatever reason.  Note also that the UWP client DOES work using that same msalXXXX://auth URI  (this is why I bothered to explain problem 1 above)

---

Visual Studio 2017  15.8.6
Xamarin.Forms  3.2.0.871581
Microsoft.Identity.Client  1.1.4-preview

---

Below is the list of strings from App.cs, as well as screenshots from my B2C setup.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    public static string Tenant = "myapp.onmicrosoft.com";
    public static string ClientID = "d43c8xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static string PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1_emailPolicy";
    public static string PolicyEditProfile = "B2C_1_profileEditPolicy";
    public static string PolicyResetPassword = "B2C_1_passwordResetPolicy";

    public static string[] Scopes = { "https://myapp.onmicrosoft.com/api/read" };
    public static string ApiEndpoint = "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoItem";

    public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
    public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}";
    public static string AuthorityEditProfile = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyEditProfile}";
    public static string AuthorityPasswordReset = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyResetPassword}";
```

[image: B2C setup for API]
[image: B2C setup for Xamarin.Forms UI]

Comment: DId you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same issue.  I can authenticate with B2C but when I call my azure functions endpoint, I get a 401.

Comment: Have you tried w/the latest version of MSAL 2.7?